# Show Light AlertDialog using Theme.Light.NoTitleBar

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I used the following line in my manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

to have no title bar and display the light version of AlertDialog in my app, like in example:
[image]

But it's displaying in dark theme still:

[image]

My Dialog Java code:

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(FreeDraw.this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setTitle("Clear Drawing?")
    .setMessage("Do you want to clear the drawing board?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());  
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
    .show();
```

How do I keep the theme light for AlertDialog?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The top dialog in your post is a Holo Light themed dialog whereas the bottom one is the older themed dialog.  You cannot get a Holo Light themed dialog on versions below Honeycomb.  Here is a little snippet I use to select the light theme based on what android version the device is running.

The `AlertDialog.Builder` will use the theme of the context it's passed.  You can use a `ContextThemeWrapper` to set this.

```
ContextThemeWrapper themedContext;
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
    themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper( FreeDraw.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar );
}
else {
    themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper( FreeDraw.this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar );
}
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext);
```

Comment: I am seeing that on my phone running JB 4.2.2

Answer (score 15):

You can use something like this when creating your `AlertDialog` :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = null;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
} else {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
}
// ... do your other stuff.
```

This code will create Holo Styled AlertDialog in newer versions and normal device based AlertDialog on devices with older version of Android.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use an `AlertDialog Builder`. With it you can set a style to your Dialog. Look the following example:
http://pastebin.com/07wyX0V3

```
<style name="popup_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/back_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/back_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It covers the entire screen white!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new Material library from google, and want to keep the theme consistent

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

Simply use this for Light `AlertBox`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```

for dark `AlertBox`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Dialog_Alert);
```